# Indirect Blender questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just posted [THIS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123821/converting-8bit-to-16bit-for-bump-maps) and it got flagged as not Blender related (which it kinda is indirectly ;P) I knew it would get flagged but there are some people that are only on this site that I highly respect their knowledge. I tried Graphic Design exchange and BA but have not got a response back yet. Should I post questions like this on META or am I just out of luck hoping one of my stack exchange heroes can shed some light on things?

Answer (score 1):

Note that [cross posting is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/238438). Post where it seems most fit (GD.SE seems like a good start to me) and if it turns out it's better fit somewhere else it'll be migrated (ideally).

If you want to talk to someone here in particular you could try asking around in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm), though if the someone you're looking for isn't there then I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: I guess I just feel like breaking rules today. lol Thanks